# Why poodles and bathtubs, but not subscript capital letters? (Unicode in Julia)

Tags: unicode, syntax, julia

I was excited to see that in Julia you can type many mathematical symbols and Greek letters and such. What is more, I saw that you can type subscript and superscript letters via `\_x` and `\^x`. Interestingly, you can type some superscript capital letters, like `\^L`, but you cannot type the corresponding subscript letter (`\_L`). Why is this the case?

More importantly though, I was scrolling through the huge [list of unicode characters one can type in Julia](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/unicode-input/), and found you can type all sorts of questionably useful stuff like poodles and bathtubs. Why can you type all these weird things, but you cannot type something like a capitalized subscript (which seems far more useful in the context of Julia)?

Who makes these decisions anyways? Is Julia just completely following a pre-determined standard, or are they making decisions themselves? (I would have thought it was a standard, but I did not think that, for instance, superscripted letters were part of the [normal list of unicode characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters).)

Comment: I missed the piece at the beginning of the Wikipedia link (second one above) that says: "As it is not technically possible to list all of these characters in a single Wikipedia page, this list is limited to a subset of the most important characters for English-language readers..."

Comment: Hey, these things really have [their practical use](https://github.com/under-Peter/OMEinsum.jl#learn-by-examples). Imagine that nice example with just plain old letters :P

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The subscript `L` isn't available because it's not part of the [Unicode standard for subscripts/superscripts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_subscripts_and_superscripts). It's not arbitrariness on the part of Julia, it's Unicode :)

In particular, see this table from the above Wikipedia page which shows the superscript `L` ("Superscript small cap ") but no subscript `L`:

[image]

Comment: At the beginning of the linked article, I see: "These characters allow any polynomial, chemical and certain other equations to be represented in plain text without using any form of markup like HTML or TeX." This seems to begin to suggest the reason why some super- and subscripts appear and others do not. Any further idea about this...? Like what chemical or "certain other" equations do they have in mind?